# Windows 10 add back button to right-click in explorer

Tags: windows-10, right-click, navigation

Similar to what you find in a browser, I would like to add the Navigate back option to my right click menu in File Explorer (Not Inet Explorer).

[This article](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/windows-right-click-context-menu/) shows how to disable or delete the options but I would like to add and option. Specifically the navigate back and forward. 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHlOE.png)

Comment: Probably better to use an advanced mouse with programmable buttons.

Comment: Thanks @moab. In my case I have a number of work stations and don't bring my mouse. I would also like it to work in my laptop pad.